# associating http request parameters from a form with a collection of objects

Tags: grails, groovy

I have an application that has Question and Answers (see domains listed below). Basically, a question `has many` answers. Each answer has an `ordinal` that determines the order which the answers will be displayed. I want the form to allow the user to change the ordinal. My problem is, I'm not sure how I can associate the input fields from the html form, with the correct answer on the server side. When I submit this form

```
<g:if test="${questionInstance.answers}">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Order</label>

        <div class="controls">
        <g:each status="i" in="${questionInstance.answers}" var="answer">
            <div><input type="text" name="answer[${i}].id" style="width:15px;" value="${answer?.ordinal}" />
            ${answer.body}
            </div>
        </g:each>
        </div>
    </div>
</g:if>
```

I get these parameters on my `update` action `question` controller (controller is shown at bottom). I want to update the ordinal for each answer but not sure how

[image: parameters]

### question object

[image]

### question domain

```
class Question {    
    DateTime dateCreated
    DateTime lastUpdated

    String body
    Answer correctAnswer
    Integer ordinal

    static belongsTo = [lesson: Lesson]
    static hasMany = [answers: Answer]

    static constraints = {
        body blank: false
        correctAnswer nullable: true,
            validator: { Answer val, Question obj ->
                // Correct answer must have this as it's question
                val ? val.question == obj : true // TODO: Give this a proper error message
            }
        ordinal unique: 'lesson'
    }

    static mapping = {
        lesson lazy: true
        answers sort: 'ordinal'
        answers cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }
}
```

### answer domain

```
class Answer {    
    DateTime dateCreated
    DateTime lastUpdated

    String body
    Integer ordinal
    String reason

    static belongsTo = [question: Question]

    static constraints = {
        body blank: false
        ordinal unique: 'question'
    }

    static mapping = {
        question lazy: true
    }

    String toString() {
        "Answer: $body"
    }

    Integer getNextOrdinal() {
        Integer ordinal = Answer.createCriteria().get {
            projections {
                max "ordinal"
            }
        }
        ordinal = ordinal ?: 1
        return ordinal
    }
}
```

### question controller

```
def update(Long id, Long version) {
    def questionInstance = Question.get(id)

    if (!questionInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'question.label', default: 'Question'), id])
        redirect(action: "lessonQuestionDashBoard", controller: "lesson")
        return
    }

    if (version != null) {
        if (questionInstance.version > version) {
            questionInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                    [message(code: 'question.label', default: 'Question')] as Object[],
                    "Another user has updated this Question while you were editing")
            render(view: "edit", model: [questionInstance: questionInstance])
            return
        }
    }

    questionInstance.properties = params

    if (!questionInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [questionInstance: questionInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = "Question: '${questionInstance.body}' has been updated"
    flash.messageType = "success"
    redirect(action: "show", id: questionInstance.id)
}
```

Comment: see Binding To Collections And Maps in http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding, making answer a list and removing id from the input name.

Comment: Sorry, will not work that way... value would have to be [ordinal:<value>]

Answer (score 0):

as described in the [docs about data binding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding) (as Martin already mentioned), you have to edit the form elements like following:

```
<g:if test="${questionInstance.answers}">
    <g:each status="i" in="${questionInstance.answers}" var="answer">
      <input type="text" name="answer[${i}].ordinal" value="${answer?.ordinal}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="answer[${i}].id" value="${answer?.id}" />
    </g:each>
</g:if>
```

This is because your hasMany Relationship from Question to Answer is from type Set. Whit this construct params looks like this:

```
params[answer][0] = [id: 123, ordinal: 4]
```

and so on. This way data-binding will work as you expect it to.

Comment: You'd think that would work. The params seem to be structured correctly but still fails to update the `questionInstance`. - [Image of parameters](http://snag.gy/Sy9AU.jpg)